# How to test the FIR filter in C++?

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response

I am almost done with design and implementation of my first FIR filter using C++. Its a Sinc-Windowed FIR filter designed for a cut off frequency of 100 Hz with sampling rate of 500, with a filter order M = 100. All the operations have been carried out in discrete time domain. **So basically my question is regarding testing to see if my filter is generating the desired response** .

I presume one way to test the output would be to apply DFT to it and check the response spectrum of the filter in the frequency domain, but for this I have to develop a function that performs the DFT on the output .

Question :To avoid this, I am looking,

---->Are there any methods that make it possible to test the filter response in the (without the need for applying DFT) time domain itself?.

----> If the above is not possible, are there are any alternative methods like some C++ DSP library with FT function's you can suggest?

Or Any suggestions and advice regarding this with your experience would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a unit test framework like [Google Test?](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/)

Comment: Nope. Is there an approach or possibility to testing FIR Filter (C++) using this framework?.

Comment: An FIR filter is deterministic; it will generate a precise output for a given input. Therefore, you can *verify* that the C++ code is generating the correct output using a unit test framework. There are plenty to choose from (e.g. Boost Test, Cppunit, see [Unit testing on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) )

Comment: HOWEVER! This does not *validate* your requirements to whether the filter gives the correct frequency response.  Since the filter is an FIR, it is relatively easy to test using something like MATLAB or Octave.

Comment: @Damien,I will start with unit impulse testing and then have a look at Matlab and Octave on how to use them. Thank you for the direction.

Comment: the *unit test* referred to above is a software engineering technique. The *unit impulse* is a mathematical construct.  The *unit test* will ensure you have implemented the software correctly.  The *unit impulse* will ensure you have created the filter has the properties that you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first basic test could be to use a unit impulse as an input signal and see if the output signal equals the impulse response (i.e. the filter coefficients). Another simple test signal is a unit step. The corresponding output should be the cumulative sum of the filter's impulse response, i.e. for $x[n]=u[n]$, the output must be

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=0}^nh[k],\quad n\ge 0$$

If you obtain the desired response for these two simple test signals, that's a good start, but I wouldn't stop there.
In general it is very helpful to use a tool like Matlab or Octave (free), or anything similar, which has built-in filtering routines against which you can check your routine for arbitrary input signals.

Comment: I would go for Python since you can call it's routines very easily from within C++ code.

Comment: How about Scilab?, Its a freeware too.

Comment: @DigitalGeeK: Any of them will do for your task, just choose what you like.

Comment: @MattL. I'm wondering, is the step response you described valid *iff* the step response is infinite in length? The reason I ask is because I have designed a C++ FIR tool that stores the operands _h[n]_ and _x[n]_. The resultant convolution function behaves as described above initially, but then tails back towards zero when the array reaches its end...?

Comment: @davidhood2: The formula is valid no matter if the impulse response (and hence the step response) is finite or infinite. Note that $y[n]$ in the above formula *can* converge to zero for $n\rightarrow\infty$. That would be the expected behavior of a high pass or band pass filter (i.e., a filter blocking DC).